Filtering an enum by ignore the associated value
Lets say I have an enum as follows:
enum AnalyticsDimension: Equatable {
    case brand
    case deviceID
    case deviceModel
    case pageName(value: String)
    case pageType(value: String)
}

Lets say I have an array
var currentDimensions: [AnalyticsDimension] = []
My goal is to store the latest value of the enum in this array
To do that, I have a function like this:
private func updateSavedDimensions(with dimensions: [AnalyticsDimension]) {
    dimensions.forEach { updatedDimension in
        if let index = currentDimensions.firstIndex(where: { $0 == updatedDimension }) {
            currentDimensions[index] = updatedDimension
        } else {
            currentDimensions.append(updatedDimension)
        }
    }
}

The issue with this is if I have .pageName("one") and .pageName("two"), these will be considered different and two records are being created in my array.
Is there a way that I can ignore the associatedValue and just compare the case in my filter without needing to add some custom == within the enum ?

You don't need a custom == specifically, but you should add an extra method that would do this comparison, perhaps called something like sameType(as:). You can do this inline, but it would be very verbose. Consider not using an enum with associated values in the first place.
